# New to PHP, trying to extract information from another website

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://na.lolesports.com/season3/split2/schedule');

preg_match('<time datetime="(.*)"', $content, $match);
$match = $match[1];

echo "$match";
?>
```

I'm trying to use that to get the dates and times of matches, but the page just takes forever and comes up blank.

Comment: are you getting the page content in the first place?

Comment: @JoãoRafael If anything, the OP should be getting this error message `Warning: preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter '>' found in...`

Comment: i was able to get the data by including > to the match: '<time datetime="(.*)">'

Comment: @JoãoRafael Good catch. Site loaded fine for me. Not sure what info the OP wants to get from it.

Comment: I think he wants to extract the "next match", if so, it was just the ">" :)

Comment: @JoãoRafael Put it in as an answer. You've got my vote. Cheers (*Peace*)

Comment: @user2676857 Not sure if João got my message. It's best that your question gets an answer, so that it does not remain in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: @Fred whatever, dont care for points haha

Comment: @JoãoRafael You're entitled to the credit João (it's only fair), which I mentioned you in it.

Answer (score 1):

As [**João Rafael**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2022937/joao-rafael) pointed out, there was a missing `>` between `"` and `'` in `<time datetime="(.*)"`

Reformatted code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://na.lolesports.com/season3/split2/schedule');

preg_match('<time datetime="(.*)">', $content, $match);
$match = $match[1];

echo "$match";
?>
```